# Session state to use only one user

Tags: asp.net, session-state

I have bool variable in my session state. When I try to get this value I get for all users. When I login like another user who doesn`t have initialize Session state, I got same value.

```
     bool aa = (bool)Session["playedSRB"];
```

I was thinking this is related to the user.

Comment: It is related to the user. What makes you think it's not at this point?

Comment: Did you try logging in with a separate browser or from a different machine? It's possible that your login/logout actions are not actually creating new sessions. You could spy this by logging in the `Session_Start` event in `Global.asax`.

Comment: I run my browser, start my program and session state value is null, then I set value to false, start program, delete line where I set value to false, logout, login like another user then I have for this user false, not null!

Comment: @rsbarro I use ajax authenication service. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384014.aspx . It is same machine.

Comment: I set breakpoint to the one line in the Session_Start, and when I logout doesn`t stop there.

Comment: Try testing with a separate browser. Login first say with IE and second with Firefox. It seems like your login/logout function is not creating a new session. Maybe you want to throw a `Session.Clear()` in your logout function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe the session state cookie is associated with who is logged in.

ASP.NET_SessionId  is the session cookie.

.ASPXAUTH is the authentication cookie (login).

Comment: Do I need to delete this ASP.NET_SessionId cookie? I use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383782.aspx function to logout.

Comment: +1: I was hesitant to upvote this at first because in my applications they are associated so I was thinking you must be out of your mind. I had to go check the original code I wrote in my base library, but I wrote the associations into my base classes myself apparently.

Comment: @gormit: In your logout routine, you need to have a method that clears all session information that should be related to the logged in user.

Comment: @gormit: In addition because of that, I would recommend against using a lot of different session variables and create a singular class to hold your information in one memory object. That way you have a universal way of getting to everything and only have to set/update/delete one object.

Comment: @Joel Etherton Is it fine to create static class for variables? What exactly you mean for one memory object.

Comment: @gormit: I don't mean static, I just mean consolidated. If you have 7 variables that all need to go into session `name, address, phone, ...` that all relate to the logged in user, it is better to have a single class (e.g.: `MyUserInfo`) that holds all of this information. That way you don't have to keep track of all of it separately.

Comment: @Joel Etherton how can I share object between pages :(.

Comment: @Joel Etherton or better to question, is sigleton class is class with sigleton pattern. Where to initalize this object?

Comment: @gormit: The singleton pattern is not good to use in this case. You may need many instances of the object in question across the AppDomain. You would still use Session to share the object between pages, but in your logout code you would add a call to `Session.Clear()`. Having a single object for the session data means you only need to worry about that variable.

Answer (score 0):

..It might not be your problem, but I'd suggest testing with true instead - a null value cast to bool converts to false.

Comment: Same thing when I set to true.